# Is there a way to know if the user has enabled "single click to open an item" in the control panel?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

My program needs to know when the user has enabled "Single-click to open an item (point to select)" in the folder options window in file explorer. I have a mouse aid program and I need to know what this setting is set to programmatically? Is this available in the registry or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's [SHGetSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762201(VS.85).aspx) when `fDoubleClickInWebView` is false

Answer (score 0):

I found this on [Kelly's Korner](http://www.kellys-korner-xp.com/xp_tweaks.htm)

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer]
"ShellState"=hex:24,00,00,00,13,a8,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  01,00,00,00,0d,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00
```

I don't know which value sets the single click mode, so you'll have to disable it and compare the registry with this string to see which it is.

The same information is on a [Microsoft support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/174490) page, but as it's referring to IE 4 and IE 5 I was worried it was outdated.

There's a [reg file](http://www.kellys-korner-xp.com/regs_edits/singleclickshell.reg) you can download, but it appears to be missing the initial open double quote.